# IPython Alias with '%s' In It

Tags: git, ipython, string-formatting, alias

So I found this really nice git command that I like, and I would like  to save an alias of it in IPython:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%Cred%ad%Cgreen%d%reset%s'
```

Unfortunately, the '%s' in the above command is interpreted by IPython's %alias magic as a placeholder for an argument so I get the following when I try to use my alias:

> UsageError: Alias  requires 1 arguments, 0 given.

I noticed that I can double up on the parentheses, like so:

```
%alias gitld git log --pretty=format:'%%C(yellow)%%h%%Cred%%ad%%Cgreen%%d%%reset%s'
```

and then I can do...

> gitld %s

...but I am a busy/lazy man.  Is there anyway to un-argument that '%s'?

Comment: Not at present, but if you'd like to try fixing it, the relevant code is here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/alias.py#L136

Comment: Fixed it, and just made a pull request.  My first one!  I must admit it was a simple change, and not the way I expected to lose my open source contribution virginity :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Commented out" alias [is now part of the ipython repo](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/8151).  From that point on the alias magic replaces "%%s" with "%s" and does not expect an argument.